# pytest function without return value

Tags: pytest

I'm trying to do a pytest on a function without return value, but obviously value is None in pytets. I was wondering if there is a solution for that?

here is function which I'm trying to test:

```
  def print_top_movies_url():
    for item in movie_link[:100]:
        print item.contents[1]
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve distinguishing None from "no value"?

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do would be to separate getting the top movies and printing them.

For example, you could have a `top_movie_urls` which looks like this:

```
def top_movie_urls():
    urls = []
    for item in movie_link[:100]:
        urls.append(item.contents[1])
    return urls
```

(or make it a [generator function](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators))

That's easy to test, and wherever you call it, you can now just do something like `print('\n'.join(top_movie_urls()))`.

---

If you really want to test the output instead, you can use pytest's [output capturing](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/capture.html) to access the output of the tested function and check that.